# How would I get a specific nested value from a fetch POST response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have made a POST request like this:

```
var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers();
        raw = "srvrwd-ui=useMe"

        var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
        };
        
        fetch("https://www.example.net", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

In console it does print the result and it comes out like this

```
{"totalResponse":{"details":false},"address":{"number":"234"}}
```

I want to get the value of `number` and the methods I have used to extract it specifically is the following:

```
.then(result => console.log(result["number"]))
```

which returns undefined

```
.then(result => console.log(result.totalResponse.address.number))
```

returns undefined again.

Is there any way I could get the specific value?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, totalResponse and address are two separate properties, so it would be

```
.then(result => console.log(result.address.number))
```

It would probably be beneficial for you to review this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects as it will explain working with objects quite well.

Comment: For those type of cases, you can start console.log from result and see what properties you have enable to continue accessing instead of try to access at once. Also, it could help to use a beautifier to see the object structure better